# "mkvirtualenv myproject" command giving "DNS server not authoritative for the zone" error

Tags: python, django, dns

I am running Windows 7 with Python 3.6 and no other versions. I installed Django through pip successfully. Yet when I try to make new virtual project, I get "DNS not authoritativer error". I am logged in and running cmd prompt as Admin. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Full error trace please

Comment: How to do full error trace?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

My PATH variable was sloppy. Instead of ending the variable with "\". I had ended it with ";"